# HTML / CSS: default borders iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, border-layout

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS and would like to give a div the same border style in CSS as a default iframe has in IE. 
I coulnt find this on Google and could not get the same styling when trying this myself in CSS.

**My CSS so far:**

```
.div-inner
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-left:1px solid;
    border-top:1px solid;
}
```

Can someone help me with this and tell me which border (or other) styles I need to apply to my div to make it look like an iframe ?

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: border: 2px inset white;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following **CSS** rule will make the div look like an iframe :

```
.div-inner{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border: 2px inset white;
}
```